# How can I open Tez app (Google Pay app in India) programmatically in React Native in Android?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, google-pay

Tez is a popular type of payment in India.

```
 tezFunc()
      {

        const url = 'com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user://';
          Platform.OS === 'android' ? 

   Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
    if (!supported) {

        Linking.openURL('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user&hl=en_IN')
    }else {
      return Linking.openURL(url);
}

 }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err))
 :
          Linking.openURL('https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/google-pay-for-india-tez/id1193357041?mt=8')
        }
```

Here I am passing the app's bundle id as a url. This works in a way that every time the Play Store gets open up, I don't know how to achieve that. I want to open the app if it is present in the device else open the Play Store link.

However I have achieved this in case of WhatsApp but It's not working in case of Tez.

This in case of WhatsApp is working

```
_whatsaap = () =>
{
  const url = 'whatsapp://send?text=. I have an enquiry, please reply me ASAP!&phone=**********';
  Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
   if (!supported) {
    Alert.alert(
      'Comet Graphic',
      'Sorry, The app is not installed in your device! Press OK to install it now!',
      [{
        text: 'OK', onPress: () =>Linking.openURL(' https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp') },
        {text: 'Cancel'},
       ], {
        cancelable: false
      }
    )
```

How to achieve this in Tez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-intent#example--check-if-an-application-is-installed

I think you could try the following:

1. Check if application is installed on user device using: 
   SendIntentAndroid.isAppInstalled('com.google.android.gm').then((isInstalled) => {});
2. If installed run:

   SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.google.android.gm').then((wasOpened) => {});

   and if you want to pass additional parameters use:

   SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.mycorp.myapp', {"com.mycorp.myapp.reason": "just because", "com.mycorp.myapp.data": "must be a string"}).then((wasOpened) => {});

Im not sure how this works but as far as i can see you can install the apk directly using:

SendIntentAndroid.installRemoteApp('https://example.com/my-app.apk', 'my-saved-app.apk').then((installWasStarted) => {});

Update: 
Please try this example code:

```
_tez = () => {
SendIntentAndroid.isAppInstalled('com.tez.blablabla').then((isInstalled) => {
    if (isInstalled) {
        SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.google.android.gm').then((wasOpened) => {
            if (wasOpened) {
                console.log("App opened");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error opening app or it was not opened");
            }
        });
    }
});}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but please can u be more specific?

Comment: more specific in a way that I dont know how to use intent and all stuffs. I am new to RN and developing line. It would be of great help if u can help me with the codes

Comment: I added the code pieces you need in the answer. You can just use these. Just follow the steps above and replace the app bundle ids. You dont need to know what a intent is in detail. You basicly send a intent to the android system that you wold like to open a application or perform an action and the os handls it for you.

I updated the answer and pasted some exmaple code check it out

Comment: thanks a lot brother... I will surely update whether it worked or not. But thanks for your valuable time.. Going to try this.

Comment: error: undefined is not a function evaluating 'RNSendIntentAndroid.isAppInstalled(packagename)'

Comment: Seems like a problem with the npm module. Have you installed it properly without errors? Can you also post your code?

Comment: ya I did install it the proper way and I also linked them. Still it throws an exception.

Comment: hmmm strange. Did you serach for the issue on the npm modules github page?
As far as i can see its a error with the module. I wish you good luck

Answer (score 2):

I have created a npm package for enabling ReactNative developers to accept payments on mobile application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-pay-tez

Try this.

Note : Google only supporting android intent for accepting payments through installed google pay app. For iOS you'll have to use omni channel for which you'll have to contact them.